# select the file to upload before sending with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

I looking to select my files on an interface before it is sent to the server....you can see my screenshot

http://screencast.com/t/G2diXiysNKrm

my script :

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <style >
            .attachmentSelect {
                display: block;
                font-family: courier;
                font-size: 11px;
                width: 650px;
            }
            ption:checked {
                background-color: -moz-html-cellhighlight !important;
                color: -moz-html-cellhighlighttext !important;
            }
            select > option {
                -moz-padding-end: 5px;
                -moz-padding-start: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 0;
            }
            option {
                -moz-user-select: none;
                display: block;
                float: none !important;
                line-height: normal !important;
                min-height: 1em;
                position: static !important;
                text-indent: 0;
                white-space: nowrap !important;
                word-wrap: normal !important;
            }
            ul,
            li {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            li {
                /*    
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1F1;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-top: 1px;
                padding: 3px;*/

                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
                border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                color: #0088CC;
                display: block;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                cursor: move;
            }
            .fl { float: left; }
            .fr { float: right; }
            .remove {
                background: url("img/delete16x16.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 16px;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                width: 16px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            .sortable-placeholder {
                background-color: #F3F3F3;
                border: 1px dashed #ccc;
                font-size: 45px;
                /*  height: 30px;*/
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            </style>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <br />
              <br />
              <!-- IMPORTANT:  FORM's enctype must be "multipart/form-data" -->
              <form method="post" action="uploadfileOne.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8"> 
                    <!-- ToUpload[] -->
                    <input  class="filestyle" value="" data-buttonName="btn-primary" id="upload" name="" type="file" value="" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ul class="attachmentSelect" >
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary"> --> 
                  </div>
                  <div class=".col-md-4"> <a id="add" class="btn btn-default" href="#" >add</a></div>
                </div>
                <!--<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="" /> --> 
                <br />
                <br />
                <!--<div class="sortable-placeholder"></div>-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <!--<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">-->
                <div id="list-input"></div>
              </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                //----------------------    
                var i=0;
                $('#add').click(function(){

                    var path= $('input#upload').val();
                    if(path !=""){
                                $('.attachmentSelect').append('<li id="file'+i+'" data-path='+path+'>'+path+' <a class="fr remove" title="Supprimer" href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a><input style="display:none;" name="file'+i+'" type="file" /></li>');
                                $('input#upload').val('')
                                i++
                    }
                });
                //----------------------
               $('.remove').on('click', function() {
                     $(this).closest('li').remove();
                });
                //----------------------
                $(".attachmentSelect").sortable({
                    cursor : 'move',
                    cursorAt : { left : 0 },
                    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
                    forcePlaceholderSize : true,
                    dropOnEmpty : false,
                    connectWith : 'ul'
                });
                //----------------------      
            });

            /**/
            $('.attachmentSelect').on('click', '.remove', function(){ 
                 var currentFile = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
                    $(this).closest('li').remove();
                    $('input[name='+currentFile+']').remove();
            });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

but the problem ..I can not request my files

firebug :
http://screencast.com/t/oqkUen7SyBIr

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$('#i_submit').click( function() {
    //check whether browser fully supports all File API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {
        //get the file size and file type from file input field
        var fsize = $('#i_file')[0].files[0].size;

        if(fsize>1048576) //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
        {
            alert(fsize +" bites\nToo big!");
        }else{
            alert(fsize +" bites\nYou are good to go!");
        }
    }else{
        alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
    }
});
```

take help from this [9lessons](http://demos.9lessons.info/multiupload/index.php)

Comment: I think your script check to find size of file ... but I want get the requests ... see my result  firebug after send 
firebug : [link](http://screencast.com/t/oqkUen7SyBIr)
.......
for example, it downloads a single file ... not selected multifile .....
thanks so mush

Answer (score 0):

finally we can't set the value to "input" with javascrip..... for obvious security reasons.

I have find another solution with this script

```
              <br />
              <br />
               <form name="upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8"> 
                  <div id="upload">
                    <input type="file" name="fileupload[]">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ul class="attachmentSelect" ></ul>
                  </div>
                  <!--<div class=".col-md-4"> <a id="add" class="btn btn-default" href="#" >add</a></div>-->
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
              </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var i=0;
                //----------------------    
                  $(document).on('change','#upload input',function(){
                    var path= $(this).val();
                    if(path !=""){
                        $('.attachmentSelect').append('<li id="file'+i+'" >'+path+' <a class="fr remove" title="Supprimer" href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></li>');
                        $(this).appendTo('#file'+i).css('display','none');
                        $('#upload').append('<input type="file" name="fileupload[]">');
                        i++
                    }
                });
                //----------------------
                $('.remove').on('click', function() {
                     $(this).closest('li').remove();
                });
                //----------------------
                $('.attachmentSelect').on('click', '.remove', function(){ 
                     var currentFile = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
                        $(this).closest('li').remove();
                        // $('input[name='+currentFile+']').remove();
                });
                //--------------------
                $(".attachmentSelect").sortable({
                    cursor : 'move',
                    cursorAt : { left : 0 },
                    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
                    forcePlaceholderSize : true,
                    dropOnEmpty : false,
                    connectWith : 'ul'
                })
            </script>
```

thank you for all help